# Deciding on Jquery plugin structure

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am new in making a jquery plugin and this is the plugin structure which i have come across on many links. I never actually got how to use Plugin methods on this page [Jquery Authoring Plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)... Can anyone explain to me that where I should write my private functions and public functions in the present structure in the following structure? As well as what does "i" and "el" comprise of?

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
    options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options );
        return this.each(function (i, el) {


        });
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
    ///options here for overiding
};
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: The format of the plugin depends on how you want people to use it. In the `each()` function `i` is the integer index of the current item in the array, and `el` is the item itself.

Comment: Ok.. So could you also tell me on the Plugin methods section on [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) page and should I be using it for public functions in my plugin or there is a more simpler approach than this?