# Jquery Plugin return On Selection/Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

On getting no answer on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305494/deciding-on-jquery-plugin-structure) , I decided to go on with this plugin structure.

```
(function ( $ ) {

$.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options );
    return this.each(function (i, el) {
     ("someiD").live("click",function() {
            UpdateCounter();
        });

    });
};

$.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
///options here for overiding
};
}(jQuery));
```

I have made a plugin in which I have to select a button to increase a counter and then I don't know how to get the updated values of the counter that is OnSelect/OnClick of the button.... Can anyone give me any insights on how should I be dealing with this without changing my plugin structure?

Comment: sorry I should have updated my post on for the code .... I am updating it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically like this:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
    options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options );

    // $(this) is your selected element, #someSelect in this case
    $(this).on('select', function(e) {
      console.log('selected!')
    })

};

// execute your plugin on the selected element
$('#someSelect').myPlugin();
```

Comment: So if I use like this var myCounter = $('#someSelect').myPlugin(); then would I get the updated value in my variable?

Comment: I don't know which variable you mean, but you can easily read out the new content of your selected option and set it to any variable you want.